# SQL export data to Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel

In Windows Forms, I use C# to export data from SQL to Excel, It was successful, I want any data greater than 2, I will highlight that cell in red, I write that but I get an error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

My code:

```
int stt1 = 0;
float temp = 2.0f;
row = 6; 

foreach (var element in datalist)
{
    stt1++;
    row++;

    dynamic[] arr1 = { element.col2, element.col3, element.col4, element.col5 };

    Range rowData = ws.get_Range("C" + row, "F" + row);

    rowData.Font.Size = 11;
    rowData.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    rowData.Value2 = arr1;

    Tag_Public.temp = Convert.ToSingle(arr1[stt1]);

    if (Tag_Public.temp >= temp)
    {
        rowData.Font.Bold = true;
        rowData.Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red); 
    };
}
```

Can someone give me an idea how to solve the problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Which line are you getting the error in? Is it happening on `arr1[stt1]`? If yes, then what is the length of `datalist`? Check the value of `stt1` on the line `arr1[stt1]` when the error happens.

Comment: What change did you make before you got the error? What line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us that much information, however one thing I noticed was that you increase stt1 at the begining of your foreach loop and later use it for accessing your array arr1. I suspect you intended to increase stt1 at the end of your foreach so that you start accessing arr1 at index 0 and not 1. Since you start with 1 and increase you are likley to exceed the array bounds which leads to the error you get.